# How to bound a Button placed on Telerik's RowDetailsTemplate to a ICommand in view's ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, telerik, telerik-grid

Considering this code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"  />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Last Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"  />
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding OpenView1Command}">Open View 1</Button> <!-- This does not work -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

The OpenView1Command is defined in my ViewModel. How do I make the binding work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, Michael, my previous answer works, so there is nothing wrong with Telerik , and to prove it, I coded this up, copy/paste/run:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    Height="350" Width="525" 
    x:Name="wnd">

<telerik:RadGridView  ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Items, ElementName=wnd}" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <TextBlock Text="This is my RowDetailsTemplate: " />
                <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=ViewModel.SomeCommand}">SomeCommand</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
</telerik:RadGridView>
</Window>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;

namespace Sample
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
        ViewModel.PropertyChanged +=(o,e)=> 
        {
            if(e.PropertyName.Equals("Proof"))
            MessageBox.Show("Button Command Binding just worked!");
        };

        InitializeComponent();

    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<SomeClass> _items;
    private DelegateCommand _someCmd;
    private bool _proof;

    public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (_items == null)
            {
                _items = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    _items.Add(new    SomeClass(string.Format("name {0}", i)));
            }

            return _items;
        }
    }
    public DelegateCommand SomeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _someCmd ?? (_someCmd = new DelegateCommand(() =>
                                                                {
                                                                    Console.WriteLine("Booya, binding works!");
                                                                    Proof = true;
                                                                }));
        }
    }

    public bool Proof
    {
        get { return _proof; }
        set
        {
            _proof = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Proof");
        }
    }


    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public SomeClass(string name) { _name = name;}

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
                return;
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
}
```

Comment: Denis, I appreciate your help. Your sample is working and I know that this is right way to bind the button's command to ViewModel's command. Anyway - I cannot make it work in my real application. I must be doing something really stupid. All the difference I can see in the code that is my view has derived from BaseView class which has ViewModel public property. Should I specify as AncestorType the base class or derived class?

Comment: Also I have tried to use ElementName but it did not worked even in your sample.

Comment: well, I you shouldn't use the base, the command should be available to the child through inheritance (as long as it is public or protected). What is the type of the class that has the property "SearchResults", and how do you bind it? - post a code sample of that, maybe that will lead us in the right direction

Comment: Here is some relevant code: <inf:ToolViewBase 
 x:Class="MyApp.Modules.AccountSearch.Views.SearchClientsView"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Modules.AccountSearch.Views" ....<telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SearchClientsView}}, Path=ViewModel.DisplaySummaryViewCommand}">View Summary</Button>

Comment: SearchClientsView - is the view class that has ViewModel public property of Type SearchClientsViewModel. The latest has public property SearchResults (an observable collection) and DisplaySummaryViewCommand DelegateCommand. The binding of the view and viewmodel is in code-behind using MEF:   [ImportingConstructor]
  public SearchClientsView([Import] SearchClientsViewModel vm)
  {
   InitializeComponent();
   ViewModel = vm;
  }

Comment: ok, looking at it, also what's the namespace in .cs for you XAML

Comment: MyApp.Modules.AccountSearch.Views

Comment: your code looks right, everything should work, assuming that ViewModel property on your SearchClientsView is public. How about another test. create a command property "TestCommand" directly on SearchClientsView, change the binding in XAML  to:  Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SearchClientsView}}, Path=TestCommand}", and put a breakpoint in the Method that executes that command -> that should work! let me know...

Comment: while you doing that, can you paste the first line of your class: public partial class SearchClientsView .., the quesion is how is this view being registered/imported/resolved, is there an interface

Comment: [Export]
 public partial class SearchClientsView :ToolViewBase, ISingleInstanceView
 {...

Comment: is your SearchClientsView gets put/resolved in IOC container?

Comment: Yes, Search is working properly - on dobleclick of the search row it opens a detailed view for the searched item. Now requirements has been changed ans instead of one view there should be a choice of multiple actions. if i put the buttons outside of the datagrid everything is working. I just whant to put the buttons right under the selected row. Simple task but I cannot make it work :(

Comment: Yes, somehow your code is not traveling up the Visual Tree and not finding the anscestor, have you tried if XAMl debug <Button Command="{Binding ..., diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>, that should send issues to output window in VS (oh,  add reference to Diagnostics from WindowsBase dll )

Comment: I am getting this error in output window: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='MyApp.Modules.AccountSearch.Views.SearchClientsView', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ViewModel.DisplaySummaryViewCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'ImageButton' (Name='UC'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: so that tells me that it can't find the ancestor, as if it's not even in the Visual Tree...is your RadGridView sitting in some popup, dock panel or something that's detached? Not sure what to tell you, running out of ideas :)

Comment: The view is derived from AvalonDock's DockableContent class. But I do not have any problems using binding anywhere else but from RowDetailsTemplate. I have had this problem before - solved by feeding grid with Collection of different ViewModels ant puting the logic there. But it was case with inline editing of complex object so it made a sense to put it on separate View/ViewModel. in this case my ViewModel will have only Commands (weird!). I am going to accept this as an answer. Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: well, we gave it a try, I am still blown away why this is not working, if you figure it out, add a comment, I'd like to see what you have discovered!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the names of you controls, but something like this should work. Basically find the anscestor type, and hook the binding:

```
  <!--assuming the ViewModel is bound to your view-->
  <UserControl x:Name="YourView"
           xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.Views">

             ....
   <DataTemplate>
        <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Views:YourView}}, Path=OpenView1Command}" Open View 1</Button> 
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Well, I know that this SHOULD work but it doesn't with telerik GridView for some reason.

Comment: as long as SearchResult and OpenView1Command command are on the same ViewModel that should work, I use telerik daily and haven't come up with this problem. To test the claim, can you try to refactor to standard/regular gridview (should be a matter of minutes), if the binding isn't working there, there is something else going on that we can't see from your post.

Comment: ok, I disagree, I'll post some code for you, that compiles and works!